# Writing this in the big O notation?

Tags: asymptotics, computer-science

I have two real variables $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ where $0 < \sigma_1, \sigma_2 << 1$.

I am getting maximal errors of the form of products of linear combinations of the two variables. For example, I have a second order error of $$\sigma_1 (\sigma_1 - 2 \sigma_2).$$

Is this the same as writing $$\sigma_1 (\sigma_1 - 2 \sigma_2) = O((\sigma_1+\sigma_2)^2)?$$
How does it work with linear combinations?

Thanks!

Comment: If both sigmas are constants, the expression is O(1), constant

Comment: What if they're not constant?

Comment: Then it depends on their order. For exanple, if they are of the same order,  the expression is O(\sigma_1^2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $0 < \sigma_1,\sigma_2$ then it is indeed true that

$$
\sigma_1 (\sigma_1 - 2\sigma_2) = O((\sigma_1+\sigma_2)^2)
$$

since

$$
-\frac{1}{3} \leq \frac{\sigma_1 (\sigma_1 - 2\sigma_2)}{(\sigma_1+\sigma_2)^2} \leq 1.
$$

Comment: Does this method imply that $O(\sigma_1) = O(\sigma_1+ \sigma_2)$? Since $0 < \frac{\sigma_1}{\sigma_1+\sigma_2} < 1$.

Comment: @user202654 yes, presuming $\sigma_1,\sigma_2 > 0$, by the definition of $O(\cdots)$.